# Showing author's page with no posts

Tags: author, author-template

I'm building a meet the team page, which will be included all team members. I'm using the author.php file template.

I have a page that shows all authors (it works with authors who have no posts). When clicked it redirects to the author page.

There, everything works fine if the author has posts, but I want it to show all authors.

As simple as outputing the author's name:

`<?php the_author_meta('first_name') . ' ' . the_author_meta('last_name'); ?>`

Only works if the author has posts. How can I display the author, even if he has not posts at all?

Comment: Maybe you can try wp_list_authors() function - make sure to set to false the "hide_empty" parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

Comment: I'm OK listing them, the problem happens when the link redirects to the author template, which hide all information if the user has no posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [get_queried_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) where the CODEX says:

> if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object

So since you have an object, you can return it values:

```
$author = get_queried_object();
echo $author->first_name . ' ' . $author->last_name;
```

And you can use the same parameters as [get_the_author_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta):

```
user_login
user_pass
user_nicename
user_email
user_url
user_registered
user_activation_key
user_status
roles
display_name
nickname
first_name
last_name
description (Biographical Info from the user's profile)
jabber
aim
yim
googleplus
twitter
user_level
user_firstname
user_lastname
rich_editing
comment_shortcuts
admin_color
plugins_per_page
plugins_last_view
ID
```